RabbitMQ/Pika: Stream connection lost: ConnectionResetError(104, "Connection reset by peer")
Below is my rabbitmq snippet. I am running long running task, connection is getting closed though my task continue to run in the background. Once the task is complete and I am trying to acknowledge the channel is closed. I tried to reconnect but Process Died as exception. What is the way to fix this? I do see this thread talks about using threading: Handling long running tasks in pika / RabbitMQ Handling long running tasks in pika / RabbitMQ But, then there are answer that inform pika not being thread safe. Any better solution? apart from threading and apart from setting heartbeat to 0?
class CreateSummary(RabbitBot):
    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        ****

    def generate_summary(self, ch, method, properties, body):
        # parse body
        # create summary based on the input

        try:
           ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
        except Exception as e:
           try:
              self._reconnect()
              self._rabbitmq_channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
           except Exception as e:
               raise e

    def consume(self):
        self._rabbitmq_channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
        self._rabbitmq_channel.basic_consume(queue=self._rabbitmq_queue,
                                         on_message_callback=self.generate_summary)
        try:
            self._rabbitmq_channel.start_consuming()
        except (pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError,
            pika.exceptions.AMQPChannelError,
            pika.exceptions.ChannelWrongStateError) as e:
            self._reconnect()
            self.consume()

